# GNU Make target completion with Zsh with Included make files

Tags: zsh, make, autocomplete

> GNU Make 4.3+
>
> OS: Mac

With the following added to the `.zshrc` file, I am able to generate auto completions for `make` at the target level for a`Makefile (or 'makefile')` containing rules in that literal file.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:make:*' tag-order 'targets'
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

However, when I group the commands into subfiles and include them via the `include *.mk` mechanic, `zsh` no longer generates the correct auto-completion statement. **Only** the targets defined in the top level makefile are output.

---

The exact file structure:

```
├── install-brew
├── install-oh-my-zsh
├── install-pathogen
├── makefile
├── mk
│   ├── get.mk
│   ├── notes.mk
│   ├── setup.mk
    ...
```

And `makefile`:

```
include mk/*.mk

foo:
  echo foo

bar:
  echo bar
```

`> make [tab]` produces:

```
> make foo
foo bar
```

And `make get-brew`:

```
if [ -z `command -v brew` ]; then ./install-brew; else echo "brew detected: `command -v brew`" >&2; fi
```

(so the makefile is working)

---

How does one configure `zsh` to generate the full user-defined target list from a makefile even when that make file includes supporting make files?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

```
zstyle ':completion:*:make:*:targets' call-command true
zstyle ':completion:*:*:make:*' tag-order 'targets'
```

this worked for me, for 2 level makefile "include":
just add to your .zshrc file.
source: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/issues/813#issuecomment-902592371

That causes the `make` completion to call `make -nsp --no-print-directory --always-make` if it detects `make` is GNU `make` to help determine the list of possible targets.

It used to be done unconditionally but [that changed to be conditional to a `zstyle` setting in 2001](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2001/msg00400.html) as calling `make` here could end-up being an expensive and potentially risky operation.

The description of that `call-command` style can be found with [`info zsh call-command`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-call_002dcommand_002c-completion-style):

> `call-command`
>
> This style is used in the function for commands such as `make` and
> `ant` where calling the command directly to generate matches suffers
> problems such as being slow or, as in the case of make can
> potentially cause actions in the makefile to be executed.  If it is
> set to 'true' the command is called to generate matches.  The
> default value of this style is 'false'.